# Rename 2000+ subfolders (Windows)

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, rename, directory

I have a hierarchy of folders on a Windows server, where 2000+ folders are named "Resources (1)". I would like to rename them to just "Resources", i.e. I need to remove a space and then "(1)". (While I've done programming before, I'm too new to shell scripting to be able to modify the somewhat similar questions and answers already here).

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Save yourself a lot of hassle and [use the free Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php).

Comment: Do all 2000+ folders have the same name, as you imply?

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "targetdir=c:\destdir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /s /b /ad "%targetdir%\resources (1)" '
 ) DO (
ECHO REN "%%a" "Resources"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Simple enough - just change the definition of `target` appropriately.